# PHP Curl can't load page

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to open a specific page (https://www.yellowpages.com.au)
I have tried simplehtmldom
I have also tried Curl
I have tried with different headers and added a certificate
I can open other pages, just not this one and would like to know how the site is stopping my access and what I can do about it.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");


$certificate = "cacert-2019-01-23.pem";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $certificate);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, $certificate);


$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't have access to `https://www.yellowpages.com.au/`. You should speak to the owners of the site on how to get data from them instead of trying to break in

Comment: Provide request and response headers and error messages if there are errors. Don't let people **guess** your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the url `https://www.yellowpages.com.au` does not serve a page, it just redirects you (via a [HTTP Location Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location)) to another url (to be specific: `Location: http://www.yellowpages.com.au/dataprotection?path=/`) that actually serves a page. in order to load that url with curl, you must tell curl to follow `HTTP Location redirects`, that can be done with [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html),

in addition to that, yellowpages.com.au blocks requests that lack a User-Agent header, libcurl sets no default User-Agent header, you can set that with the [CURLOPT_USERAGENT option](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERAGENT.html), here is a working example:

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init('https://www.yellowpages.com.au');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'libcurl/'.(curl_version()['version']).' PHP/'.PHP_VERSION);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

outputs:

```
$ php foo4.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>

        <title>Yellow Pages&reg; | Data Protection</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=2" />

    <!--[if (lt IE 9)&!(IEMobile)]><script src="/assets/ie/respond.sensis-9575467dfbc008e5b0d486dc4f481624.js" type="text/javascript" ></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if (lt IE 10)&!(IEMobile)]><script src="/assets/ie/custom-event-ie9.js" type="text/javascript" ></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if (lt IE 10)&!(IEMobile)]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/ie/gradient-hacks-ie89-12453d23f1fec3d9d46e56cc6e023576.css"/><![endif]-->

        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?" async defer></script>
        <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"/>

</head>
<body style="border-width: 0;
                background-color: #EDEDED;
                font-size: 85%;
                line-height: 1.3;
                margin: 0;
                font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;" id="">


        <div style="padding: 10px 15px;
                    height: 70px;
                    min-height: 45px;
                    background-color: #ffce00;
                    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffce00, #fedb55, #ffce00);
                    box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 7px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);">
            <div style="position: relative;
                        max-width: 1240px;
                        margin: 0 auto;">
                <a href="/">
```

(capped)